# How to make a separate thread for each object, asynchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, ccxt

How to make a separate thread for each object in exchanges, asynchronously

```
async def async_client(exchange):
    client = getattr(ccxta, exchange)()
    tickers = await client.fetch_tickers()
    print(threading.active_count())
    await client.close()
    return tickers


async def multi_tickers(exchanges):
    input_coroutines = [async_client(exchange) for exchange in exchanges]
    tickers = await asyncio.gather(*input_coroutines, return_exceptions=True)
    a = print("async call spend:", time.time() - tic)
    return tickers


def asyncios():
    return asyncio.run(multi_tickers(exchanges))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    exchanges = ['binance', 'bitget', 'bitmart', 'bitvavo', 'bybit', 'gate', 'huobi', 'kucoin', 'mexc', 'okx']
    tic = time.time()
    for _ in range(len(exchanges)):
        b = threading.Thread(target=asyncios)
        b.start()
```

I want all exchanges to be requested at the same time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You generally don't need (and don't want) one thread per network request, this would be inefficient. Use async-await, instead, for instance with the aiohttp package.

Comment: In your code you forgot to wait for the threads to finish. Use the `.join()` method on threads to do that.